# How to check valid selection when adding data from combo boxes?

Tags: c#, validation, binding, combobox, win-universal-app

I have two combo boxes and an add button on my View, both combo boxes must have an item selected from them in order for there to be a valid selection.

I tried disabling the add button's enabled property if both combo boxes have no selection, but currently the button is re-enabled if only one of the combo boxes has been selected.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this situation, or point out where I've gone wrong with this setup?

The button's enabled property is bound to the property in the ViewModel:

```
 //This button enable property is bound to the combo boxes being selected  ----->
        <Button x:Name="addGradeBtn"
                Grid.Row="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Command="{Binding Path=AddGradeCommand}"
                Content="Add Grade"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonEnabled,
                                    Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <ComboBox x:Name="subjectCmbBx"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="199"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Subject"
                  Header="Subjects"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects}"
                  PlaceholderText="Pick a subject"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSubject,
                                         Mode=TwoWay}" />


        <ComboBox x:Name="ordinaryGradeCmbBx"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="170"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                  Header="Grades"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding OrdinaryGradePointKV}"
                  PlaceholderText="Pick a grade"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedOrdinaryGrade,
                                          Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Visibility="{Binding IsHigher,
                                       Mode=TwoWay,
                                       Converter={StaticResource BoolToNonVisibilityConverter}}" />

        <ComboBox x:Name="higherGradeCmbBx"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="170"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                  Header="Grades"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding HigherGradePointKV}"
                  PlaceholderText="Pick a grade"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedHigherGrade,
                                          Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Visibility="{Binding IsHigher,
                                       Mode=TwoWay,
                                       Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

And this is the scaled down version of my ViewModel:

namespace LC_Points.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repository = App.ScoresRepository;

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //call methods to initilise list data
        InitSubjectTypes();
        InitOrdinaryGradePairs();
        InitHigherGradePairs();
    }

    public List<ScoreModel> Subjects { get; set; }
    public List<StringKeyValue> HigherGradePointKV { get; set; }
    public List<StringKeyValue> OrdinaryGradePointKV { get; set; }

    //Button enabled binding set based on the combo boxes being selected -->
    private ScoreModel _selectedSubject;
    public ScoreModel SelectedSubject
    {
        get { return _selectedSubject; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedSubject)
            {
                _selectedSubject = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSubject");
                //I set the buttons enabled property to true is the combo box has been selected,
```

but I only want it to be enabled if both combo boxes have been selected --->
                    ButtonEnabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ButtonEnabled = false;
                }
            }
        }

```
    private StringKeyValue _selectedHigherGrade;
    public StringKeyValue SelectedHigherGrade
    {
        get { return _selectedHigherGrade; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedHigherGrade)
            {
                _selectedHigherGrade = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedHigherGrade");
                ButtonEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ButtonEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private StringKeyValue _selectedOrdinaryGrade;
    public StringKeyValue SelectedOrdinaryGrade
    {
        get { return _selectedOrdinaryGrade; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedOrdinaryGrade)
            {
                _selectedOrdinaryGrade = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedOrdinaryGrade");
                ButtonEnabled = true;

            }
            else
            {
                ButtonEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MultiBinding for Button IsEnabled like below,

```
  <Button.IsEnabled>
     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CheckIfBothSelectedMultiConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Combo1" />
                <Binding Path="Combo2" />
            </MultiBinding>
</Button.IsEnabled>
```

Check the condition in CheckIfBothSelectedMultiConverter Convertor, if both value are true return true else false.

```
public class IsEnabledCheckConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{  
    public object Convert(object[ ] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
      if(Convert.ToBoolean(values[0]) && Convert.ToBoolean(values[1]))
        {
            return true;
        }
     return false;        
}

public object Convert(object[ ] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
     //convert back Logic
}
}
```

This is what i got for Multi Binding in Win RT/Universal App

```
 <TextBlock FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Cyan">
  <mb:MultiBindingLinker.Attach>
   <mb:MultiBindings>
    <mb:MultiBinding TargetProperty="Text" Converter="{StaticResource ConcatMultiConverter}">
      <mb:Binding Path="StringValue" />
      <mb:Binding Path="Text" ElementName="ConcatTextBox1"/>
      <mb:Binding Path="Text" ElementName="ConcatTextBox2" Converter="{StaticResource ToUpperCaseConverter}"/>
      <mb:Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
 </mb:MultiBinding>
 </mb:MultiBindings>
 </mb:MultiBindingLinker.Attach>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I added the converter class, but I'm getting two errors, 1.IMultiValueConverter could not be found, and there is no option to import it, this is a Windows RT project, is there an alternative?
2.'Convert' is a method which is not valid in the current context, this is given at the 'if' statement.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: include the name space System.Windows.Data for IMultiValueConverter, both errors will go of.

Comment: Updated the question tag, this is a Windows RT/Universal project not WPF, which is why I'm getting the errors, is there any alternative?

Comment: Ohh. but still you can use IMultiValueConvertor because you are using converter anyway... Converter supports IValueConverter and IValueConvertor so i believe you can achieve it.